# Intersection between array of hashes but returning the full hash

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

There are two arrays of hashes

```
actual = [{id: 1, text: "A", type: "X", state: "enabled"}, {id: 2, text: "B", type: "X", state: "enabled"}]

expected = [{text: "A", type: "X", state: "enabled"}]
```

I need to get the :id of all Hash not included in "expected". The comparison has to be done using three keys (text, type, state). In this case

```
results = [{id: 2}]
```

At the moment I am using this but it's very long and not performing for a big array. Is there a better way?

```
 actuals        = actuals.map{|a| a.slice(:text, :type, :state)}
 expected       = expected.map{|a| a.slice(:text, :type, :state)}
 not_expected   = actuals - expected
      
      results = actuals.select{|actual| 
         not_expected.find{|n| 
            n[:text]   == actual[:text] &&
            n[:type]   == actual[:type] &&
            n[:state]  == actual[:state]
         }.present?
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
actual = [{id: 1, text: "A", type: "X", state: "enabled"}, {id: 2, text: "B", type: "X", state: "enabled"}]
expected = [{text: "A", type: "X", state: "enabled"}]
comparable_expected = expected.map { |e| e.slice(:text, :type, :state) }

results = actual.select do |a| 
  not comparable_expected.include? a.slice(:text, :type, :state)
end

resulting_ids = results.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
exp = expected.first
  #=> {text: "A", type: "X", state: "enabled"}

actual.reject { |h| h == h.merge(exp) }.map { |h| h.slice(:id) }
  #=> [{:id=>2}]
```

[Try it](https://repl.it/join/wfvosivk-caryswoveland)

Hashes in `actual` are rejected if they are unaffected when merged with `exp`, meaning that the hashes being merged have the same values for all the keys in `exp`. Each remaining hash `h` in `actual` is then mapped to `{ id: h[:id] }`, using [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

One advantage of this approach is that the code need not be changed if `exp` is changed to a hash having different keys.